# Counting number of words that have each alphabet letter

Tags: julia

From the [Think Julia](https://benlauwens.github.io/ThinkJulia.jl/latest/book.html#_exercises_10) book, I wrote the following code to count the number of words that have each alphabet letter:

```
abc = "abcdef"
letter_count = 0
fin = open("words.txt")
for letter in abc
    for line in eachline(fin)
        if letter in line
            global letter_count += 1
        end
    end
    println("$letter has $letter_count")
    global letter_count = 0
end
```

However, the code only counts the number of occurrences of the letter 'a'.
I could not figure why this code fails.

It returns:

```
56613 have a
0 have b
0 have c
0 have d
0 have e
0 have f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a wrong order of loops (i.e. the outer loop should iterate letters). You can fix it like this (I have also simplified the code a bit):

```
for letter in "abcdef"
    letter_count = count(x -> letter in x, eachline("words.txt"))
    println("$letter has $letter_count")
end
```

However iterating the words.txt file once like this will be faster:

```
let counts = zeros(Int, 6)
    for line in eachline("words.txt")
        for (i, letter) in enumerate("abcdef")
            counts[i] += letter in line
        end
    end
    counts
end
```

You could also achieve the desired result using broadcasting like this (I report it as I found it an interesting solution):

```
julia> letters = "abcdef"
"abcdef"

julia> sum(in.(hcat(letters...), eachline("words.txt")), dims=1)
1×6 Array{Int64,2}:
 56613  16305  30466  30648  76168  11277
```

**EDIT:**

the difference between `eachline(fin)` and `eachline("words.txt")` is the following:

- `eachline("words.txt")` opens (and closes when done) a new stream every time it is called;
- `eachline(fin)` uses the same stream, which means that after the first loop of the iteration is finished we are at the end of the stream and nothing is left to be read in it.

You can retain the `eachline(fin)` approach if you move to the start of the stream after each iteration like this:

```
abc = "abcdef"
letter_count = 0
fin = open("words.txt")
for letter in abc
    for line in eachline(fin)
        if letter in line
            global letter_count += 1
        end
    end
    println("$letter has $letter_count")
    global letter_count = 0
    seekstart(fin)
end
close(fin)
```

Note that I have added one significant line to your code (and also added `close(fin)` as you should always close opened streams). But, at least for me, it is not a very clean approach so I did not want to recommend it in the first place.

Comment: The outer loop is already iterating letters in my original code. But I found that if I modify the line `for line in eachline(fin)` to `for line in eachline("words.txt")`, the code works, but I don't understand why in the previous way it failed.

Comment: I will comment in the answer.